# XML de Configuração

Tags: xml, vb.net

Estou com dificuldade em entender um caso de XML

A tarefa que tenho que fazer é a seguinte

> Se no cadastro de pelo menos um insumo,  o centro de armazenagem
>   (tabela esmart, campo10) for EXTC o sistema considera que se trata
>   de beneficiamento. O que preciso é alterar este CA(Centro de Armazenagem), pois houve uma
>   necessidade no Pennagh de se cadastrar um novo e precisamos que esta
>   informação não fique fixa no programa. A informação pode ficar no
>   banco de dados ou  XML de configuração

Apesar de ver alguns exemplos no google, não entendi como coloco essa informação em XML de Configuração

Meu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Database>
  <registro>
    <provider>msdaora</provider>
    <idioma1>Português</idioma1>
    <idioma2>Español</idioma2>
    <idioma3>English</idioma3>
    <smtp>smtp.'...'.com.br</smtp>
    <limitelinhas>1000</limitelinhas>
    <notificacao>teste@teste.com.br</notificacao> 
    <SCA>http://localhost/sca/WebService/Acesso.asmx</SCA>
    <GARANTIAConnectionString>Data Source = desenvolvimento; User Id = kawasaki; Password = teste</GARANTIAConnectionString>
    <PECASConnectionString>Data Source = desenvolvimento; User Id = kawasaki; Password = teste</PECASConnectionString>
    <ERPSPConnectionString>Data Source = kmb; User Id = kawasaki_Pennagh; Password = kwl0026_Pennagh</ERPSPConnectionString>
    <ERPMAConnectionString>Data Source = kmbma; User Id = kawasaki; Password = kwl0026</ERPMAConnectionString>
    <ERPConnectionString>Data Source = orclprd; User Id = kawasaki; Password = teste</ERPConnectionString>
    <RELPECASConnectionString>Data Source = ORCL10; User Id = kawasaki_Pennagh; Password = kwl0026_Pennagh</RELPECASConnectionString>
    <corporationConnectionString>Data Source = desenvolvimento; User Id = kawasaki; Password =desenvolvimento</corporationConnectionString>
    <PennaghAMTSTConnectionString>Data Source = Pennagh; User Id = PennaghTESTE; Password = PennaghTESTE</PennaghAMTSTConnectionString>
    <PennaghAMPRDConnectionString>Data Source = Pennagh; User Id = PennaghTESTE; Password = PennaghTESTE</PennaghAMPRDConnectionString>
    <PennaghSPPRDConnectionString>Data Source = ORCL10; User ID = kawasaki_Pennagh; Password = kwl0026_Pennagh</PennaghSPPRDConnectionString>
    <KCAAMConnectionString>Data Source = Pennagh; User Id = PennaghCOMPONENTETESTE; Password = PennaghCOMPONENTETESTE</KCAAMConnectionString>    
    <PEDConnectionString>Data Source = desenvolvimento; User Id = kmbpedvei; Password = teste</PEDConnectionString>     
    <HWMSConnectionString></HWMSConnectionString>
  </registro>
</Database>
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem que tu tem que trabalhar amigo?

Comment: vb.net, desculpe esqueci de colocar na Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um site muito bom para primeira leitura de xml, http://www.macoratti.net/10/08/vbn_xml1.htm

Só para melhorar a explicação, o XML é composto por nós pais e nós filhos, ou seja,
no seu XML tem:

```
<Database> -----> Nó Pai
  <registro> ----> Nó Filho (Cabeçalho)
    <provider>msdaora</provider> ----> Nó de Itens
    <idioma1>Português</idioma1> ----> Nó de Itens
    <idioma2>Español</idioma2>   ----> Nó de Itens
    ...
  </registro> 
</Database>
```

É tudo questao de atenção mesmo, faça suas próprias variáveis e vc entenderá o XML direitinho.

Lembrando... para ler os itens, é obrigatório ler o Nó Pai, o Nó Filho (Cabeçalho), e depois os itens... um exemplo em Delphi que fiz.

```
NoPai := xmldoc_nfe.DocumentElement.ChildNode['Database'];
NoFilho := NoPai.ChildNode['registro'];
NoItem := NoFilho.ChilNode['provider'].Text; 
NoItem2 := NoFilho.ChilNode['idioma1'].Text;
NoItem3 := NoFilho.ChilNode['idioma2'].Text;
```

A logica é essa aí, espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Cara ajudou demais essa explicação. Já tinha ouvido falar em NóPai e NóFilho, mas não tinha entendido até agora.
Muito obrigado !

Comment: Obrigado cara, fico feliz que tenha ajudado.